# Is this generalizing?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

> A big disadvantage of online shopping is that there is a big chance
>   you will buy something that doesn't fulfill your expectations. It's
>   logic because you can't see `a` product personally and if you can't see
>   it and touch it, you will probably buy the wrong thing.

Instead of the `a` article, I would use there `the` because I'm assuming that I'm talking about the product in general. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either *a* or *the* would be acceptable and unremarkable here.

You have said this with *a*, introducing an unspecified product you might see and purchase online.

Someone else might say this with *the*, speaking of *the product* as coreferent with *something that doesn't fulfil your expectations.*